# Nuxt robots.txt using nginx & pm2

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, pm2, robots.txt

I'm using nginx and pm2 to serve a nuxt app (SSR).
I tried to use the [sitemap module](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/) and the [robot.txt module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/robots-module#readme).

The sitemap module works fine and is accessible at `/sitemap.xml`.

However the `robots.txt` file is not accessible through nginx. Using `nuxt build` and `nuxt start` in local it works fine and I have access to `/robots.txt`. But using nginx I have a 404. Not the Nuxt 404 but the nginx one. All other inexistant url show the Nuxt 404

Using Nuxt SSR and the robot module does not generate a `robots.txt` file. It's a middleware and response to [the `/robots.txt` url is dynamically generated on each request](https://github.com/nuxt-community/robots-module/issues/33#issuecomment-561144440)

Why do I have that 404 with the robot module but not with the sitemap?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is in your `dist` folder when you `nuxt build`? Do you see your `robots.txt` file? Also, why are you talking about the sitemap if it works and your issue is not related to it?

Comment: In the `dist` folder I have two folders (client & server) and a `sitemap-routes.json`. I tal about the sitemap as I think it should have been exposed the same way as the `robots.txt` file. But I don't have a `robots.txt` file anywhere. I think the issue is linked to nginx as in local env the `robots.txt` file is exposed through `/robots.txt`.

Comment: Can't you put the `robots.txt` in `/static`?

Comment: It's not a file that i wrote myself, it's generated using [nuxt robots.txt module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/robots-module). The `robots.txt` file is different depending on the NODE_ENV and other parameters. The thing is, for some reason, I can't access to the file when the app is served by nginx

Comment: There is probably a configuration to expose the `/static` directory. Did you try to host it on a platform without requiring any nginx configuration? You do have `target: server` (default), right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Google Cloud App Engine (GAE) which also uses Nginx to host my Nuxt.js app and had the same problem as yours - I can access my sitemap.xml unlike robots.txt.

For GAE configuration I use an app.yaml file where among all configurations you can set handlers for static files. You can explicitly set that static files requests will be serve from a Nuxt's 'static' folder. As always types of potentially requested files are set as a regexp that shows a list of file extentions (e.g. .(gif|png|txt)$).

In my case I have a '.txt' file among other static files to serve from Nuxt's 'static' folder. That's why Nginx was looking for my robots.txt directly in the 'static' folder and did not give a chance for Nuxt to generate it.
So when I removed the '.txt' extention everything work fine and now I can get my robots.txt.

I'm not familiar with Nginx configurating, but maybe you should check what extentions of static files it is serving and exclude a '.txt' extention serving from Nuxt's 'static' folder.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly serve a robots.txt from Nginx without actually having access to the physical file you can define the content of the robots.txt file in the Nginx .conf file.

**Allow access to all User-agents:**

```
location /robots.txt {return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow:\n";}
```

**Disallow access to every User-agent:**

```
location /robots.txt {return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";}
```

Comment: It's not what I want, the `robots.txt` file needs to be generated by Nuxt as the output is different depending on NODE_ENV and other parameters

Comment: ok then locate the robots.txt on nuxt root path and pass in Nginx alias.

Comment: This contains static files which are mapped to the root directory of your site. For example, putting an image called logo.png in this directory would make it available at /logo.png. This is good for meta files like robots.txt, favicon.ico, and other files you need available.

Comment: I might not be clear about how the nuxt robot module works. But I'm using Nuxt with server side rendering. The robot module work as a middleware and generate dynamically the response to the `robots.txt` url. So there is no `robots.txt` file to expose through nginx